# How to implement redirect in kernel.request event properly?

Tags: 8, redirection, event-subscribers

I can reach site by multiple aliases. Business logic requires to do some redirects in case of accessing be an alias. E.g: alias1.dev -> site.dev/landing-page.

I've implemented `EventSubscriber` for this job. When I'm testing in browser it seems to work fine, but under the hood redirection workflow is:

alias1.dev -> alias1.dev/front-page -> site.dev/landing-page

So I've redirect to `page.front` in the middle. How to avoid it?

I was debugging a lot but found nothing useful.

Comment: This solved my issue: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/201293/1178