# D8 - Homepage Redirect gets cached

Tags: caching, redirection

Is there any way to keep the redirect logic of the homepage uncached but to keep the page itself cached?

I have a "location by ip" redirect on the "/". This logic then redirects to the correct homepage. "/de", "/en", "/es" and so on.

```
public function onRespond(FilterResponseEvent $event) {


    if ($event->getRequestType() !== HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST) {
        return;
    }

    $response = $event->getResponse();

    $is_front = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage();

    //REAL DOMAIN HOMEPAGE <front> *.com - before redirect
    if($is_front && $response->getStatusCode() == "301" ){




        // IP LOCATION
        $geo_locator = \Drupal::service('geoip.geolocation');
        $ip_address = \Drupal::request()->getClientIp();
        $user_address = strtolower($geo_locator->geolocate($ip_address));



        if($user_address == "de"){
            $response_new = new RedirectResponse('/de');
            $response_new->send();

        }
...
```

Page Caching:

```
function ca_cache_preprocess_page(&$variables){
   $is_front = \Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage();
   $current_uri = \Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
   if($is_front){
    $variables['page']['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
   }
}
```

This to function correctly the logic can't be cached of course. But is the only solution to make the homepage not being cached at all?

This seems wrong to me.

Comment: First of all, don't send the response, return it in the event `$event->setResponse($response);`, otherwise your code doesn't stop running and produces a second response which then will get cached, what you don't want. Second subscribe to a request kernel event with a priority > 27, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201273/problem-with-event-subscriber-kerneleventsrequest-is-not-fired-on-cached-pag

Comment: thank you. I return now the event with a setResponse instead of sending it. The script works now like expected. Even with the internal cache turned to max 3 hours the redirect is not cached - which is good.

Could you explain to me why there is still the need to request a kernel event? Thanks

Comment: After having a closer look I think it works because you are replacing one redirect response with another one.