# Why are KernelEvents not triggered on cached pages?

Tags: event-subscribers

Why Kernal events not triggering on cached pages.I have tried using priorities..

**$events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onRequest', 27];**

Services.yml file

```
tags:
  - { name: 'event_subscriber', priority: 210, responder: true}
```

MyEventsubscriber.php

```
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onRequest', 27];
    return $events;
   }

    public function onRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $response = $event->getRequest();
   \Drupal::logger('my_event_subscriber')->notice('Page Hit');
   }
```

It is not logging when the page is served from cache... Any other approach?

Comment: Not enough info.

Comment: On every page hit I am just logging the entry to the logger using KernaResponse event...
..but when the page is served from page cache the kernal event is not triggering

Comment: Use a priority >27 or a middleware, depending on the level of page caching you want to intercept, see both answers https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/201273/problem-with-event-subscriber-kerneleventsrequest-is-not-fired-on-cached-pag